# Eclipse Photon Connects to Internet but Not Software Repo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I can use the internal browser to browse the internet, but I get Connection Timeout when I try to add a new software repository URL.  I get the same issue when I try to connect to the Eclipse Marketplace.  Anyone know what I can try?  I've searched around and tried some solutions but no one has this specific issue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall? If so, have you explicitly configured it at Preferences > General > Network Connections?

Comment: [1] Re "_I've searched around and tried some solutions_" => Update your post to specify what solutions you have tried, and the errors you got. [2] Re "_no one has this specific issue_" => What exactly is your "specific issue"? If it is simply a connection timeout then that is a common problem. [3] Are there any relevant errors in the Error Log? (**Window > Show View > Error Log**)

Comment: If you don't have the Error Log view, its contents are in your workspace's .metadata/.log file.